# Is there a way to extract the most relevant feature from a dataset of tensor Time Series?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, feature-extraction

I have generated a dataset with the following code and I want to use a methods to extract the most relevant feature maintaining the dataset structure

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.svm import SVC


# Generate synthetic data with 100 samples
n_samples = 100
n_sequences = 10
n_features = 5

X_list = []  # List to hold the sequences
y = []

# Generate synthetic data
for _ in range(n_samples):
    sequence = np.random.rand(n_sequences, n_features)
    label = np.random.randint(0, 2)
    X_list.append(sequence)
    y.append(label)
```

I tryed to use SelectKBest and Recursive Feature Elimination from sklearn but I need to create a 2D array and so lose the Time Series structure.

```
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=5, step=1)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
selector.support_
selector.ranking_
```

Is there an algorithm that can take as input e list of tensors (where each column is a feature) with its label and indicate to me the most relevant feature?

Comment: what do you mean by "_the most relevant feature_" ?

Comment: also, side comment...  why have you imported numpy 3 times ?

Comment: @D.L I mean the feaature that best classify my data